# Debug complex return statement

Tags: c++, debugging, totalview

I am using totalview as a linux C++ debugger. Functions in our code often look something like this

```
double foo() {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    return bar(a,b);
}
```

where some preliminary work is done and than a more or less complex function `bar` is called a the return statement.

This is hard to debug with totalview, since the interesting return value can not be observed easily. Totalview can not evaluate the expressing `bar(a,b)`. I can rewrite the code as

```
double foo() {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    const auto retVal = bar(a,b);
    return retVal;
}
```

Now, I can place a breakpoint at the return value and observe the in- and output of my function `bar`.

How can I do this without introducing a new (useless) variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the compiler optimise out the "useless" variable, by a process called *named return value optimisation*, and leave it in. (Personally though I would help the compiler as much as possible by using the return type of the function explicitly rather than `auto`; so there's no potential type conversion at the `return` stage.). For what it's worth, I do this all the time, even with heavy objects such as `std::vector`. You can always check the generated assembler if you suspect the compiler is making superfluous copies.

Then you can set a breakpoint at the appropriate place as you know.

In some debuggers you can inspect the function return value directly by peeking at a register, but this is by no means universal.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: I can do that. The problem is that the case without the additional return variable is within our large code base. Thus, I would need to edit all files for debugging.

Comment: @schorsch312: Well, only the ones you need, on a step-by-step basis.